# Wordpress export exceeds memory limit

Tags: php, wordpress

While trying to export a *very* large wordpress site, I keep running into an out of memory error from php.

I've changed my memory limit in php.ini to

```
memory_limit = -1
```

but I'm still getting this error from wordpress' exporter in my apache error log

```
HP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/webapps/enterprise-web-root/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2474, referer: http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/wp-admin/export.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has it's own default value for the maximum memory usage and it sets it `admin.php` with an `ini_set` call.

See here *Wordpress 3.5.2 /wp-admin/admin.php:109*

```
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', apply_filters( 'admin_memory_limit', WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT ) );
```

To fix the problem, you'll need to adjust the value. I set mine to an arbitrarily high number to quickly get the export

```
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', apply_filters( 'admin_memory_limit', '4096M' ) );
```

A value of "-1" should make that memory limit uncapped completely.

Comment: You should do this using the listed filter, not by modifying core.

Answer (score 1):

**Then you should consider a Database transfer/backup :)**

It's the wiser, safer, faster choice for large sites.

**PS**: For a tool that does this easily, google 'Navicat'.
*Might work with the MySQL Workbench too, but I don't use it.*

Comment: Database backups and transfers support a very small subset of export use cases, specifically use cases where you are doing a one to one move from wordpress to wordpress with no merging. But +1 for suggesting a solution and providing a few tools.